# How to select a radio button followed by text with XPath?

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a radio button with value as HTML as follows:

```
<div class='result'>
<span>
<input type='radio'/>
option1
</span>
<span>
<input type='radio'/>
option2
</span>
<span>
<input type='radio'/>
option3
</span>
</div>
```

I tried the following XPath, but this isn't working:

```
//span[contains(text(),'option1')]/input[@type='radio']
```

Please help me write XPath for this.

Comment: could you specify what you want to select exactly, the text, or the input tag, both ?

Comment: I was looking for input tag . below suggested xpath's worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two text nodes in target `span`: the first one is just an empty string before `<input>` and the second- after `<input>` (the one that contains `"option1"`)

And your `XPath` `//span[contains(text(),'option1')]` means *return span that contains "option1" in first text node*.

You can use one of below expressions to match required `input`:

1. `//span[normalize-space()="option1"]/input[@type="radio"]`
2. `//span[contains(text()[2],'option1')]/input[@type='radio']`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't use `text()` here. Because this function returns a sequence of child text nodes of current `span` element. There are 2 text nodes in your example:

```
<span>
<input type='radio'/>
option1
</span>
```

1st text node is between `<span>` and `<input type='radio'/>` containing just a newline.

2nd text node is between `<input type='radio'/>` and `</span>` containing `option1` text plus 2 newlines (at the begining and at the ending).

`contains` function expects a string argument instead of a sequence. I think it will take only first text node from the sequence, which contains just a newline.

If you need to select `input` followed by some `text` node you can use the following expression:

```
//input[@type='radio'][contains(following-sibling::text(), 'option1')]
```

If you need to select `span` containing text `option1` and `input` with `@type='radio'`, you can try the following expression:

```
//span[contains(., 'option1') and input/@type='radio']
```

If you need to select `input` instead of `span` then use the following expression:

```
//span[contains(., 'option1')]/input[@type='radio']
```

I can suggest you the following resources to gain some information about XPath. W3C recomendations contains a full description of XPath. If you use XPath 2.0 then you can look at:

- [XML Path Language (XPath) 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/)
- [XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Functions and Operators](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/)

For XPath 3.0 look at:

- [XML Path Language (XPath) 3.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/)
- [XPath and XQuery Functions and Operators 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/)

These recomendations are big enough and hard to read. But you can find in these documents [a list of all available axes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#axes) including `following-sibling::`, [a description of `text()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#abbrev), [a description of `contains()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains), etc.

Also there are a lot of brief XPath tutorials. For example you can look at [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/index.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you please suggest me some  websites where I can find / learn more about this for free

Comment: I've added a list of resources to the answer

Answer (score 0):

There are two text elements per `span`. One precedes the `input` element, and one follows it, but the first one is essentially empty.

In this code I find the `input` elements, then their parents, then the second text elements of those `span` parents.

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> selector = Selector(text=open('temp.html').read())
>>> for item in selector.xpath('.//input[@type="radio"]/../text()[2]'):
...     item.extract()
...     
'\noption1\n'
'\noption2\n'
'\noption3\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to select option 1

```
//input[@type='radio']/preceding::span[1][contains(.,'option1')]
```